# Rails JSON API render raw JSON string as proper JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I have a Rails model (ActiveRecord) with a string field that contains a JSON document. This has to be the case for several reasons (i.e. it can’t be migrated to HStore or something), but that's irrelevant to this question.

I currently have a JSON api for this model, and I like for it tu return the nested JSON as JSON rather than a string, i.e. without quote escaping.

```
class ModelsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @models = Model.all
    render json: models, only: [:id, :json_document]
  end
end
```

This currently returns a JSON where each `json_document`is teated as a string, rather than a nested JSON.

Comment: just use https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

Comment: Or https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Comment: Thanks @itsnikolay, but even using jbuilder, how can I make it not escape the quotes in the json string? The same thing happens.

Comment: This issue has a workaround: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/issues/204  https://gist.github.com/rwz/14c0d8a5187b69922bb4